# Why Output of PHP script and MySQL database data are not same?

Tags: php, mysql

Please refer to the following image. In this image number **(1)** is what the field **position** in my database **userdb** looks like before I run my code. Number **(2)** is what change I am expecting in the position field of some rows after I run the code. The value of the position field of second row is primarily 2 what I want to be changed to 3. Similarly, The values of the position field of third, fourth and fifth rows are primarily 3, 4 and 5 respectively what I want to be changed to 4, 5 and 6 respectively. So, I run the following code and in my browser I see what I expect. However, In the database I see wrong data is inserted, like number **(3)** on the image. Notice that my last expected value of the position field is 6 (for fifth row), but I am getting 6 in all rows!!!

[image]

Here is the code I run:

```
            $requestedPosition = 2;  $oldPosition = 6;

        for($i=$requestedPosition+1; $i <= $oldPosition; $i++){

        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE userdb SET position = '$i' WHERE position='{$requestedPosition}' ");

            echo 'Old Position: '.$requestedPosition.' is now: '.$i.'<br>';
        $requestedPosition++;
        }
```

I think something must be wrong in the mysql query. If I comment out the query I get expected result in browser. However, to insert those data into database I need to run the query but when I do it, I get wrong data inserted in database. I am on windows, running PHP 5.3.13, MySQL 5.5.24.

**Most Confusingly,** in the for loop, if I change *$i=$requestedPosition+1;* to *$i=$requestedPosition;* I get 2,3,4,5 inserted (in 2nd,3rd,4th,5th row respectively) rather than 6,6,6,6. However, I want 3,4,5,6 inserted (in 2nd,3rd,4th,5th row respectively), so I had to use *$i=$requestedPosition+1;* in for loop, and when I do, Code gets Mad!!! So, do I :( Stuck with this (with bad headache) for last two days!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a slight flaw in your logic.

The first time that your loop runs, you're updating one row - you're updating the row with position 2 to be position 3. This is fine.

But the second time the loop runs, you're updating all rows where position is 3 to be position 4 - and there's two of them now, the one from the table, and the one you've just updated. The same happens on the third and fourth iteration.

You can probably do this more elegantly, with one call:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE userdb SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >={$requestedPosition} AND position <= ${oldPosition}' ");
```

I've not tested that, but it should at the least give you an idea.

Comment: Hi, the query you gave isn't working for some reason ("position = position + 1", is this right?), but the flaw you detected in the logic is really really helpful. I will work on that and update here as soon as it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @flight-87 - glad it helped. `position=position+1` should increment `position` for each row that matches the WHERE clause. If you get it working, feel free to edit this answer and add in what actually works!

Comment: The code you gave actually worked. The reason it didn't work first time is because it had a little typing mistake and missing quotations. I updated the query later and it worked. Here is the query: `$query = mysql_query("UPDATE userdb SET position = position + 1 WHERE position >= '{$requestedPosition}' AND position < '{$oldPosition}' ");` 
Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Huh. That's really interesting - do you have the position set up as a varchar field, by any chance?

Comment: No. The position field is set as INT. Why? do you see anything unusual with the query?

Comment: Normally if it's an INT, you don't need to quote values. So I'm confused as to why that was giving an error. On the other hand, since you've got it working, it's pretty much moot :D